# In bootstrap,how to make svg responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When reducing the window size , image and text should also to be reduced ?

I want to use arrows from the circle to point out the text points which is round the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may do something like

```
 <style>
@media ( max-width:1295px) {
.yourmenu{
 //do your css coding here, you may tweak the margin, padding, float of your menu

 }
}

</style>
```